# jquerymobile 1.4.2 goes in loop on select dialog

Tags: jquery-mobile, select

I have a simple page with a select menu (long dialog), an href dialog call and a tabbed content.

When I select an option the page came back and the header goes into a loop showing a new row for each autorefresh, while the page shows the tabs don't tabbed.
I use the same header on various pages but I get the problem only with this tabbed page.

Any tips?

```
 <div data-role="page"  > <!--  start header -->
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
  <a href="#nav-panelmenusx" data-icon="bars" data-position="left">Menu</a>
  <a href="#nav-panelinfodx" data-icon="info" data-position="right">Help</a>
  <h1 style="margin:0;padding:0">
  <form action="" name="selectloc" method="post" data-ajax="false">
  <input type="hidden" name="setssid" value="1">
  <select name="formname" data-mini="true" id = "selectlocation" data-native-menu="false" data-force-dialog="true" >
   <option value="n1" >label1</option>
   <option value="n20" >label20</option>
   </select>
    </form>
    <script>$('select').change(function() {
        $(this).parents('form').submit();
        });</script>
    </h1>
    </div>
    <!-- /header -->
   <div data-role="content" id="container" data-content-theme="d"  >
     <a href="index.php?page=123" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline" data-transition="pop" data-ajax="false">label</a>
     </div>
    <div id="tabs" data-role="tabs" style="max-width:600px;margin:auto;"  >
     <div data-role="navbar">
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#weekly" data-ajax="false">Weekly</a></li>
       <li><a href="#montly" data-ajax="false">Montly</a></li>
        <li><a href="#yearly" data-ajax="false">Yearly</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="ui-body-a ui-content" id="weekly" > ......  </div>
     <div class="ui-body-a ui-content" id="montly" > ......  </div>
     <div class="ui-body-a ui-content" id="yearly"> ...... </div>
   </div><!-- //end tabs -->
   <!--- start footer -->
  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b"> ....  </div>
   <!-- /footer -->
   <!-- panels-->
    <div data-role="panel" id="nav-panelmenusx" data-display="overlay"> .... </div>
    <div data-role="panel" id="nav-panelinfodx" data-position="right"  data-display="overlay">...</div>
  </div> <!-- // end page -->
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Cay you clarify your question? It is massively confusing. Explain step by step what's happening.

Comment: well, I will be more clear.

Comment: 1) I choose an option from the dialog selector 2) the page change according to the selection done 3) the new page refresh itself in an infinite loop, and for each refresh I see a new header row under the previous one. 4) the page container show the 3 tabs not tabbed but sequentially.

Comment: I solved using the right jquery script:  $('#mySelect').change(function()
 {
     $('#myForm').submit();
 });

Comment: Here some more info, the issue happen in: 
- Firefox last version 29.0.1 (loops)
- in explorer 11 runs fine 
- in Chrome not runs at all (form is not submitted)